# Some email is sending some are not

Tags: magento2, aws, smtp

I have an AWS EC2 server and some users are getting an email, some users are not.

I have my DNS records setup from Amazon SES.

I can confirm SMTP is working (Also since I get all my emails!)

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587
depth=4 C = US, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU = Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=3 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
250 Ok
```

Comment: May EC2 has some issue with OpenSSL.

Comment: do AWS servers have a /var/syslog (or similar) file? Normally for email problems, I find the answers of the receiving server there with an error notice